# List Active events via HP ilo?

Tags: hp, imm2, lenovo

If you ssh to a Lenovo IMM card, you have the "syshealth activeevents" command to list the currently active events (HW issues, etc.).

**Q:** But what is the same command for this function on the HP-ilos? Is there any similar, via SSH?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Look at the server’s IML log either from the OS or the ILO interface.

“hplog -v”

It's better to do this from the OS.

If you *must* SSH directly into the ILO, you should really be scripting this. In general, you can access the IML log via SSH interactive CLI and use the `show /system1/log1/recordn` command, where "n" is the record number in IML.

Or from the CLI.

```
[root@xt ~]# ssh -l Administrator c2-esx1ilo show /system1/log1/record*
Administrator@c2-esx1ilo's password:
show /system1/log1/record*
status=0
status_tag=COMMAND COMPLETED
Wed Mar  7 10:24:31 2018



/system1/log1/record*
  Targets
  Properties
    number=-1
    severity=Informational
    date=12/17/2014
    time=00:33
    description=Maintenance note: IML cleared through hpasmcli
  Verbs
    cd version exit show
```

Comment: "show -a" could do it.. Thanks.